# Samsung Fold, Settings screen items looks strange

Tags: samsung-one-ui, samsung-galaxy-fold

I've recently updated the Galaxy Fold to Android 10, OneUI2.1.

On the outer screen the setting items looks really strange:

[image]

I think those switches need to be in one line with the title and subtext items. This screen is small, but I think before the last update it was working fine.

This is the good way (screenshot is taken from another Galaxy /not Fold/ phone):

[image]

Can I do something to fix this beyond waiting for Samsung to fix this in some future release?

According to @MarianD, I have changed the font size to the smallest available:

[image]

Here is how it looks like (nothing is changed, except the font size):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to select the *smaller font size* in Settings.

Comment: Please see my updated question. Changing font size does not solve this unfortunately.

Comment: Nor in the landscape orientation?

Comment: Outer screen is not supporting landscape mode. When I try using the rotate function there is a toast: "Can't use Auto rotate because the screen doesn't support landscape mode."

Comment: But it looks good on the inner (large) screen.